# Is there a way to get device battery and memory stats remotely?

Tags: applications, battery, ram

I am searching for a way to get the device battery and memory statistics of my friend's device on my phone/web (definitely with his permissions, i don't intend to hack his device). Is there any web or android solution available?

Comment: Team viewer is not exactly the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't you ever heard of [Airdroid](https://www.airdroid.com/) ?.

[image: Sample image from Google images]

You can see *Battery status* and *memory statistics* at upper right corner and lower right corner respectively.( this is web view.)

AirDroid is available for all platforms.

Comment: In this case, the target device must either be connected via usb or wifi network, am I right?? I want something that can show me the stats remotely.

Comment: No... I think you haven't tried it yet.

Comment: well, I'll check it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Install Airdroid and tap on Add Device option.

Comment: Can it be used for multiple devices? I mean, can I monitor more than one device with a single account?

Comment: I guess , you can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70807/discussion-between-harry-and-ali-waris).